# How do I calculate induced drag?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift, drag

How would I go about solving this problem?

An aircraft has 6000lbs of total lift and a downwash angle of 6 degrees. Remember that the total lift vector is tilted aft by HALF the downwash angle. What is your induced drag?

Comment: what have you tried? why do you think you don't know how to answer?

Answer (score 1):

You would solve this problem by drawing the lift vector being tilted back at half the downwash angle, then apply some trigonometry to find the horizontal bit of the lift vector.